# run python through openssh

Tags: python, openssh

I have made a connection between my openssh client and server. Both sides are window machine. I fail to do the followings:

1. Enter the python command line interface on my SSH client side, which can be done by entering "python" directly through a command line.
2. I want to run a python script on a server side by calling it on my client side. This script calls a commercial library to download data from a commercial database.

I can do both perfectly through remote desktop on the server side, but when I use openssh to connect, all fail. Any way to solve, especially item (2)?

Comment: Please show what you did so far (some code) - and insert it into your original question. You may also want to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0):

If Python is installed on the remote server as `C:\Python27` and the script is `C:\Foo\bar.py`, then get [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/). It contains the program `plink.exe` which can execute remote commands.

The command for you should be

```
plink.exe user@remote C:\Python27\python C:\Foo\bar.py
```

as explained in http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.64/htmldoc/Chapter7.html#plink-usage